# GNU make in Xcode

Tags: xcode, xcode4, makefile

Is it possible to use GNU `make` in Xcode 4? It's said that Xcode supports GNU `make` but I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create a new project you need to select `Mac OS X` => `Other` => `External Build System`. This will let you use `make` or any other build system to integrate legacy or cross-platform code into Xcode. It's not as clean as using a native project, but it works. A better solution might be to use [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/) if you need cross-platform support including native Xcode projects.

Comment: in xcode 8 it's in `Cross-Platform` -> `Other` -> `External Build System`